# How to change Hash color in rhtml-mode in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I'm using [rhtml-mode](https://github.com/eschulte/rhtml) in Emacs.

When I write a Hash in a way like `:key => "value"` then `:key` is properly colorized.

But with `key: "value"` style the colorizing doesn't work. Only color of `:` is changed.

I tried to change rhtml-mode a bit. The mode seems to load ruby-mode internally if the text if is braced in <% %> tag.
Oddly when I write a Hash in ruby-mode both type of writing are properly colorized.

I'm using default ruby-mode in Emacs24.

How can I find the place (by line number) where the color of Hash key is defined?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: <kbd>C-h v</kbd>`rhtml-in-erb-keywords`. This will open a buffer showing you the regexp for rhtml keywords. There will be a link straight to where it is defined in the elisp file. You can see its definition [here](https://github.com/eschulte/rhtml/blob/master/rhtml-fonts.el).

Add the following to your .emacs file:

```
(add-hook 'rhtml-mode
          (lambda ()
           (font-lock-add-keywords nil
            '(("\\([0-9a-zA-Z_]*:\\)" 1
              font-lock-constant-face t)))))
```

This will make Emacs apply the colouring determined by `font-lock-constant-face` to anything that matches the regexp `"\\([0-9a-zA-Z_]*:\\)"`. This might match more than you want, so you may want to fine tune it.

I'm not sure there's a particularly easy way to find out exactly where the colour for a given keyword is found. You can always do <kbd>M-x</kbd>`describe-face` with the point over the word you want information on. This will tell you how Emacs thinks it should be coloured - something like `font-lock-keyword-face`. <kbd>C-h v</kbd>`font-lock-keyword` will tell you how Emacs decided that, but not in a very helpful way.

The simplest way is probably just to open the source code for the mode you're in and search in that for where it defines keywords. You can open the source code with <kbd>C-h f</kbd>`rhtml-mode`, which will open a help buffer with a link to the source.